# CrafterCMS WebDAV configuration for delivery

Tags: crafter-cms

In this documentation: https://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.1/developers/remote-assets.html#by-passing-remote-assets-in-delivery-for-webdav

> To avoid proxying the WebDav /remote-assets in Delivery ...

It implies you can run Crafter Delivery with URLs like "/remote-assets/webdav/profile1/mypath/logo.png" just like in Studio. However, the WebDav related configuration is discussed in the context of Studio:

https://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.1/site-administrators/studio/webdav-profiles-configuration.html

I understand not letting delivery proxy WebDav is the right thing to do, but for documentation completeness, how do you configure WebDav profiles for delivery? e.g. what is the XML file path in a delivery-only environment.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration path is the same for Studio and Delivery, in the file that's referenced in the link you provided. Then you publish this file so that Delivery can pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem now:

```
cd /opt/crafter/authoring/data/repos/sites/sample
ls -l sandbox/config/studio/webdav
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 michael  admin  812 Apr 29 13:26 webdav.xml
ls -l published/config/studio/webdav
ls: published/config/studio/webdav: No such file or directory
```

The publishing process missed the 'webdav' folder and file altogether. Using the above example, I assume this file should exist:

```
published/config/studio/webdav/webdav.xml
```

Is this considered a Deployer bug?

Answer (score 0):

You need to publish the `webdav.xml` configuration so the Deployer can process it.